# JAVA Generics design

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance

My current abstraction model does not work. I am not sure why and how should I fix it. Please refer the following classes.

```
public class ErrorCaptchaRequired extends AbstractError {

    public String getCaptchaUrl(){
        return this.captchaUrl;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractError<E extends AbstractError> {

    public E getError(int errorCode){
        if(error_code == 1)
           return new ErrorCaptchaRequired("abc", "abc", "abc");
        if(error_code == 2)
           return new AnotherErrorType();
    }
}


    public class MyObject<E extends AbstractError>{
        private E error;

        public E getAbstractError(){
            return error;
        }

}
```

Later on I want to use it like this:

```
AbstractError<ErrorCaptchRequired> myError = myObject.getAbstractError();
String captchaUrl = myError.getCaptchaUrl();
```

Compilation error during return statement: `Incompatible types` But I am not sure why, as in my understanding since I've parametirized class I can return any type which extends from `AbstractError` and `ErrorCaptchaRequired` is extending it. Could you please suggest a fix or better design? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post the *complete* code. `AnotherErrorType` is missing, as is a final return statement in `getError()`, as is any indication of which line gets the compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is raw (untyped) types. Raw types have all generic info stripped from them - hence no type match.

The type of `AbstractError` is itself raw: Change:

```
public abstract class AbstractError<E extends AbstractError> {
```

To

```
public abstract class AbstractError<E extends AbstractError<E>> {
```

Next, `ErrorCaptchaRequired` extends the *raw* (untyped) form of `AbstractError`, so every instance of `ErrorCaptchaRequired` is then raw.

Change:

```
public class ErrorCaptchaRequired extends AbstractError {
```

To:

```
public class ErrorCaptchaRequired<E extends AbstractError<E>> extends AbstractError<E> {
```

And change:

```
public class MyObject<E extends AbstractError>{
```

To:

```
public class MyObject<E extends AbstractError<E>>{
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer! I did what you said, but unfortunately still getting compile time error on line `return new ErrorCaptchaRequired("abc", "abc", "abc");` `Incompatible types`

Comment: You are still using it raw. Try something like `return new ErrorCaptchaRequired<SomeAbstractErrorClass>("abc", "abc", "abc")` or define `ErrorCaptchaRequired` to always have the same type for `AbstractError`, eg `class ErrorCaptchaRequired extends AbstractError<SomeConcreteAbstractErrorClass> {`